# Vlookup function

Tags: validation, lookup

Object A has a price.  We change it sometimes.  When an order comes in for object A, I'd like the price to not change.

Order has a lookup to object A.

We're trying to produce a validation rule so that if any orders have that record on object A as a lookup, you can't change then price.

Id = Vlookup($ObjectType.ObjectA.Fields.Id , $ObjectType.Order_*c.Fields.objectA*_c, Id )

Or in English, look at all the orders, and if one of them has this object a's id in its lookup field, don't let me change the price.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this with a `VLOOKUP` validation rule until Saleforce loosens the restrictions on the `VLOOKUP` function.

According to the [help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#VLOOKUP):

> The field_on_lookup_object must be the Record Name field on a custom object.

Using the starting point in your question, This means you can't use `$ObjectType.Order_c.Fields.objectA__c` as the `field_on_lookup_object`.

The only possible workaround is if the value of Order_*c.ObjectA*_c.Id is also used as the Order__c.Name thus allowing you use the validation rule:

```
Id <> VLOOKUP($ObjectType.Order__c.Fields.Id, $ObjectType.Order__c.Fields.Name, objectA__c)
```